# Javascript - Creating an event listener for an exported class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to create a class that supplies an event listener and handler for a html canvas object to respond to when left and right arrow keys are pressed. my project has 2 files a game's classes file and the game's main file

these are the functions that would normally go into the games main file. but I'm trying to make them into a class that can be exported.

```
// unmodified code
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
   }
}

 function keyUpHandler(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  }
   else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
     leftPressed = false;
   }
}
 document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
```

// actual answer is below

```
export class Paddle {
  constructor (world) {
    this.canvas = world.canvas,
    this.ctx = world.ctx,
    this.paddleHeight = 10;
    this.paddleWidth = 75;
    this.paddleX = (this.canvas.width - this.paddleWidth) / 2;
    this.rightPressed = false;
    this.leftPressed = false;
    // do i have to make a attribute for the event handlers?
    // or do i just add the listeners here?
  }

 draw()  {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(this.paddleX, this.canvas.height - this.paddleHeight, this.paddleWidth, this.paddleHeight);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
}

keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

keyUpHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}   
listener() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler, false);
}
}
```

Comment: `paddle.rightPressed = true;`

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to move those handler functions and event listeners into the class object, I just haven't made class functions with events like this before. ill update code to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really quite close - but in your `keyHandler` functions, you have this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
}
```

There is no global variable `rightPressed` - it exists only in the class `Paddle`. Change your key handlers to this:

```
keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        this.rightPressed = true; //Changed here
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        this.leftPressed = true; //Changed here
    }
}

keyUpHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        this.rightPressed = false; //Changed here
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        this.leftPressed = false; //Changed here
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is change the `listener()` function in `Paddle` like this:

```
listener() {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler(e), false);
    document.body.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler(e), false);
```

And create the instance of your class like this:

```
var player = new Paddle(world);
```

And you need to put all the functions into the constructor for it to work.

Comment: I must not be calling it right I'm getting this error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.keyCode')" 

Im calling them like this `paddle.keyDownHandler();
paddle.keyUpHandler();
paddle.listener()` if i add an 'e' argument to the handlers I get errors that e isn't defined.

Comment: `Paddle` is the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: is there a way to have the event listener in the class as well? the purpose of the class is to supply everything for the game and the main js file just needs to require and call the functions. yes i can do it many ways but for this project if i add any code to the html it defeats the purpose

Comment: I'm calling the functions `paddle.listener()
paddle.keyDownHandler();
paddle.keyUpHandler();` in this order but its not producing the same result as if the functions were in the main file. i get the error 'can't find variable e' but if i put 'e' in the handler functions it says e isn't defined.

Comment: No, you need to create an instance (`var player = new Paddle(world);`) and then call them with player.

Comment: yes that has been established i call it var paddle = new Paddle(world)

Comment: No the handler functions should be called automatically by an event listener.

Comment: I moved the handlers and listeners into the class constructor and it started working. this whole time i had them outside of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Create object that contains properties keyDownHandler and keyUpHandler as a functions and keyDown and KeyUp as a constants in the module

```
// Module my-module.js
var foo={
rightPressed:false;
leftPressed:false;
keyDownHandler:function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        this.rightPressed = true;
    }
   else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        this.leftPressed = true;
    }
}
keyUpHandler:function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 39) {
         this.rightPressed = false;
     }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
         this.leftPressed = false;
     }
  const keyDown=  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler, false);
 const keyUp= document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler, false);
}
export {foo};
```

Import the Module

```
import{foo} from 'my-module';
```

Use the constants

```
foo.keyUp;
foo.keyDown;
```

Comment: You need to bind the functions: `this.keyDownHandler.bind(this)`.

Comment: `rightPressed = true` should be `this.rightPressed = true`. Class properties don't become variables in JavaScript.

Comment: im confused on this syntax. I don't have too much experience so bare with me, in my class object i have a constructor and after that I create functions, where would i put this code into my class object?

Comment: Put in your class as an object which contain all the function as key:value pair like the code I write for you then when you want to use it you will reference it as Paddle.foo.keyDown and Paddle.foo.keyUp

Comment: ohhh okay yeah this is working i can get the events to fire off and call the handler, just got to apply movement now